# How to load csv data to mysql table using mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

The below My SQL query working for load csv data to table

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 
'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads\\sales3.csv'
INTO TABLE ttsales
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

But not working while using in stored procedure

As per my search I found that LOAD DATA will not work due to security reason

ERROR:

```
Error Code: 1314
LOAD DATA is not allowed in stored procedures
```

Can we have other alternatives to load csv data

Comment: @digijay Thanks for the response, but that article is not answer of my question. I need solution only in stored procedure. Not any external mechanism I want to create.

Comment: There isn't one..

Comment: Use LOAD_FILE(), load all the data into a variable then parse and save it.

Comment: Voting to close this as a duplicate question. I understand you said you need a solution only in a stored procedure, but no matter how much you need it, the software is not implemented to allow that.